# What is the current when there are no resistors?

Tags: voltage, current

How come I always see videos with what seems like a random amount of mA flowing from a battery with a certain amount of voltage?

For example, what if a wire had 0.13 ohms resistance and a battery had 5V electrical difference. That would mean that 38 Amps should be the current (right?).

```
I=V/R
I=5V/0.13ohms
I=38A (about)
```

Okay, so I'm editing this now using internal resistance, of about 1ohm.

This gives about 4.5A, so is this correct?

Why are common schematics showing some amount of mA shouldn't it be something like what I've shown, or do they have hidden resistors?

Comment: What is the internal resistance of the battery you are using?

Comment: Are you talking about a real battery or an ideal model of a battery?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson An ideal model

Comment: @HandyHowie it isn’t a real battery but if it were would I just be able to find it on the battery itself?

Comment: On the datasheet possibly - http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nh22-175.pdf

Comment: @HandyHowie, okay accounting for that I get about 4A but that is still no where near close to the mA I see on diagrams

Comment: Show the circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka Okay, I did that and edited the entire question accordingly.

Comment: So, you have seen videos of a battery shorted out with a random mA flowing, yes?

Comment: @Andyaka No, I'm just watching normal videos, but you can see that mA is showing and not A, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMD32gyHVQw&list=PLYS_1w0FFIANdG78JyJu3tsumsXVIcXUB&index=5

Comment: @BeastCoder2 That video had LEDs in the circuit, the battery wasn't shorted by a single wire. LEDs have resistance.

Comment: So is the new edit correct?@Andyaka

Comment: Your new circuit it now putting 5V into an LED that is only expecting possibly 2V or 3V (as in the video), so you will have a far higher current.

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes I will fix this and, was I correct about what the current should be? That is, with no resitors?

Comment: The 38A would have been correct for an ideal battery and the wire specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So why isn't it?", while solving circuits we assume the wires to have zero resistance, otherwise it's specified that the resistance of the wire isn't zero and also the value of that resistance is given. If it were a real battery it would have some internal resistance, so simply add the internal resistance to the total resistance of the circuit, in your case the resistance of the wire and calculate the current the way you did it before.

Comment: Where could I find internal resistance?

Comment: @BeastCoder2  On the datasheet possibly - data.energizer.com/pdfs/nh22-175.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It would be if the battery you are using could supply that much current.

Comment: where could you find out how much current a battery could supply?

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved with more explanation.  Maybe describe why a battery could or could not supply that much current.